# Keep part of string based on certain characters in a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, lambda

I know there have been a lot of questions around this topic but I didn't find any that described my problem. I have a `df`, with a specific column that looks like this:

```
colA   
['drinks/coke/diet', 'food/spaghetti']
['drinks/water', 'drinks/tea', 'drinks/coke', 'food/pizza']
['drinks/coke/diet', 'drinks/coke']
...
```

The values of `colA` are a string NOT a list. What I want to achieve is a new column, where I only keep part of the values that contain 'coke'. Coke can be repeated any number of times in the string, and be in any place. The values between `''` don't always contain en equal number of values seperated by `/`.

So the result should look like this:

```
colA                                                               colB
['drinks/coke/diet', 'food/spaghetti']                           'drinks/coke/diet'
['drinks/water', 'drinks/tea', 'drinks/coke', 'food/pizza']      'drinks/coke'
['drinks/coke/diet', 'drinks/coke']                              'drinks/coke/diet', 'drinks/coke'
...
```

I've tried calling a function:

```
import json
df['coke'] = df['colA'].apply(lambda secties: [s for s in json.loads(colA) if 'coke' in s], meta=str)
```

But this one keeps throwing errors that I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split on comma and `explode` to create a Series. Then use `str.contains` to create a boolean mask that you could use to filter the items that contain the word "coke". Finally `join` the strings back across indices:

```
s = df['colA'].str.split(',').explode()
df['colB'] = s[s.str.contains('coke')].groupby(level=0).apply(','.join).str.strip('[]')
```

Output:

```
                                                colA                                  colB  
0             ['drinks/coke/diet', 'food/spaghetti']                    'drinks/coke/diet'  
1  ['drinks/water', 'drinks/tea', 'drinks/coke', ...                         'drinks/coke'  
2                ['drinks/coke/diet', 'drinks/coke']     'drinks/coke/diet', 'drinks/coke'
```

Comment: This method throws following error: TypeError: You have to supply one of 'by' and 'level', but I don't really understand why, because you do provide a level-statment

Comment: @Octavarium how is `df` indexed? Maybe try `df=df.reset_index()` before running the code and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, it was because I was still working in dask, after I computed the df, it worked :).

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the string into a list and then making the check for **coke** in the list, something like this:

```
import json
df['coke'] = df['colA'].apply(lambda secties: [s for s in json.loads(colA.split("/")) if 'coke' in s], meta=str)
```